# Notification when a wifi scan is performed by the system

Tags: notifications, wifi, system, osx-snow-leopard, network-scan

I am currently porting a windows application on mac 10.6 which uses wifi.
I implemented CoreWLan notifications which only pop up when there's a change on the wlan interface.

I want to be notified when the system performs a scan, basically when you open airport.

I know that there's a state of CWInterface which is "scanning" but i haven't found any notif that i could use with that.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already know about NSNotifications and how they work. The NSNotification name you'll need is: CWScanCacheDidUpdateNotification

Your code should look something like this...

```
[[[NSNotification center] defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethod:) name:CWScanCacheDidUpdateNotification object:nil];
```

If you don't know how NSNotifications work, I suggest looking at the NSNotification guide. Odd's are, you'll need to use them at some point in your application. It's worth learning about.

Comment: Hi Tanner,
The "CWScanCacheDidUpdateNotification" notification only exists since 10.7, i am looking for the equivalent on 10.6.